# Rewrite rule for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I'm pretty new to wordpress and I'm trying to create a recipes blog.

I've created a custom taxonomy for ingredients:

```
register_taxonomy( 
    'ingredient', 
    'post', 
    array( 'label' => 'Ingredient', 
           'hierarchical' => true
         ), 
    array( 'rewrite' => array (
                            'slug'=>'recipes-with'
                        )
    );
```

Everythings works and my urls are like

`www.mysite.com/recipes-with/onion`

but I'd like my urls to be like

`www.mysite.com/recipes-with-onion`

I've tried to look into `add_rewrite_rule()`, but I can't seem to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's how I resolved the issue with toni_lehtimaki help, too.

1) I removed the `rewrite` array in the args argument of register_taxonomy so it became:

```
register_taxonomy( 'ingredient', 'post', array('label'=>'Ingredient', 'hierarchical'=>true));
```

2) Then I added some rewrite rules

```
add_rewrite_rule('^recipes-with-(.*)/page/([0-9]+)?$','index.php?ingredient=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^recipes-with-(.*)/?','index.php?ingredient=$matches[1]','top');
```

3) The last thing I needed to do was adding a filter

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'change_ingredients_permalinks', 10, 2 );

function change_ingredients_permalinks( $permalink, $term ) {
    if ($term->taxonomy == 'ingredient') $permalink = str_replace('ingredient/', 'recipes-with-', $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}
```

4) Flush rewrite rules (you only need to go to settings->permalink and click save)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with this with the `add_rewrite_rule()`:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^recipes-with-([^/]*)/?','index.php?ingredient=$matches[1]','top');
```

I did some testing for the above, and it works well when you use it for one taxonomy at time. Here is the code from my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_ingredient_tax' );
function create_ingredient_tax() {
    register_taxonomy( 
            'ingredient', 
            'post', 
             array( 'label' => 'Ingredient', 
            'hierarchical' => true
            ), 
            array( 'rewrite' => array (
                        'slug'=>'recipes-with'
                    ))
        );
}
// Remember to flush_rewrite_rules(); or visit WordPress permalink structure settings page
add_rewrite_rule('^recipes-with-([^/]*)/?','index.php?ingredient=$matches[1]','top');
```

I then used `taxonomy-post_format.php` template fiel from WordPress **twentyfourteen** theme to test that this works. I also flushed rewrite rules for the new rule to become effective.